# How to Read Word Document in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, file, ms-word

I am new to this stuff, not sure if this can be achieved, I am expecting a bunch of word documents daily, which (structured data)  I need to process and store its values to my POSTGRES. I searched over the internet, all I could find is storing the Word document in Blob, Bytea format, do encode, decode, etc, which is again returning text that I can not process. Can this be achieved, if so can you please provide a sample code that can count words/characters/lines in the word document, I can extend that to my need and requirement. I am using Ubuntu on AWS,

```
show server_encoding;
UTF8
```

I have tried below

```
pg_read_file('/var/lib/postgresql/docs/testDoc.docx');
pg_read_binary_file('/var/lib/postgresql/docs/testDoc.docx')
encode(pg_read_binary_file('/var/lib/postgresql/docs/testDoc.docx'),'base64')
decode(encode(pg_read_binary_file('/var/lib/postgresql/docs/testDoc.docx'),'base64'),'base64')::text;
```

Regards
Bharat

Comment: Sounds like you just shouldn't use Word files for your data interchange. Use some plaintext files such as CSV or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the [OpenXML library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) from Microsoft.
This is a .NET Frameowrk based OSS library that maps office documents as objects.
With this library you can build, for example, a program that extracts informations and send data to your PostgreSQL.
Tis library is available for the .NET Core framework too, so you can build a program tha can be run on Ubuntu too [.NET Core library on NUGET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DotNet.Core/).

Another way is to write a Java program. Same concept.
In Java you can use [Apache POI library](https://poi.apache.org/) to read office documents.

Remember that an office document is a compressed file (with ZIP algorithm) that contains XML data, that represents the document.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use some front end language to read the docx files and upload them to Postgres.

In Ruby you could:

Install the docx and pg gem.

```
gem install docx pg
```

and then create something like the ruby file:

```
require 'docx'
require 'pg'

doc = Docx::Document.open('document.docx')
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'postgres_db', user: 'username', password: 'password' )

doc.paragraphs.each do |p|
  conn.exec( "INSERT INTO table paragraphs (paragraph) VALUES ( $1 )", [ p ] )
end
```

I'm sure this could be done in Python or whatever language you know best.